# Simplify code that adds dictionary value with highest count to an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of individual animals, and an array of relevant species. I want to add the higher of cats and dogs to my array of relevant species. The array of individual animals may not have the requested species, in which case species_count returns `{}`.

`species_count` takes in an array of animals and groups them by species. Example:

```
animals = ['chihuaha', 'german_shepherd', 'golden_retriever', 'tabby cat', 'siamese cat'}
species_count(animals, DOG) = { species: 'dog', count: 3 }
species_count(animals, CAT) = { species: 'cat', count: 3 }
species_count(animals, MOUSE) = {}
```

The below can be improved, I think. Ruby has all sorts of magical methods that surprise me.

```
dogs = species_count(animals, DOG)
dog_count = dogs.fetch(:count, 0)
cats = species_count(animals, CAT)
cat_count = cats.fetch(:count, 0)

if dog_count >= cat_count && dog_count >= 3
    relevant_species << dogs
elsif cat_count >= 3
    relevant_species << cats
end
```

Comment: What is addition_count?

Comment: How can you let the algorithm know that `german shepherd` is a DOG, for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will probably be the way to do it:

*Simplified code:*

```
relevant_species = [DOG, CAT, MOUSE]
  .map { |animal| species_count(animals, animal) }
  .sort { |a, b| a[:count].to_i <=> b[:count].to_i }
  .last
```

*OR step by step:*

```
# returns array of [{ species: 'dog', count: 3 }, ... ]
species_counts = [DOG, CAT, MOUSE].map { |animal| species_count(animals, animal) }

# sorts the array based on the count value. to_i is to account for nils
sorted_species_counts = species_counts.sort { |a, b| a[:count].to_i <=> b[:count].to_i }

# returns the last element (with the highest count value) to be assigned to relevant species
relevant_species = sorted_species_counts.last
```

Comment: Very nice! Thank you